# PlutoSliderServer buggy with MultiCheckBox

Tags: julia, pluto.jl, plutoui

I am trying to deploy a [Pluto notebook](https://plutojl.org/) using the [PlutoSliderServer](https://github.com/JuliaPluto/PlutoSliderServer.jl) package and while the deployment does take place, I am observing some buggy behavior with the [PlutoUI](https://github.com/JuliaPluto/PlutoUI.jl) package elements; specifically the MultiCheckBox. This only happens when the SliderServer runs the  notebook; it works just fine when Pluto is running it. I am wondering if someone else has encountered this.

Here is a MWE:

```
using  PlutoUI

begin
    sites = ["France","Germany","Russia","China"]
    groupdict = Dict(zip(sites,[[:blue, :white, :red], 
        [:black, :red, :yellow], [:blue, :red, :white], 
        [:red, :yellow]] ))
end

@bind loc Select(sites)

@bind col MultiCheckBox(groupdict[loc])
```

[image]

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/JuliaPluto/PlutoSliderServer.jl/issues/103#issue-1620127609) on Github but then on second thought felt I should have asked around here first to see if someone has encountered something similar.